# Clear local storage on closing all tabs or entire browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I clear the local storage by closing all the tabs of the same domain (not closing one tab) or the entire browser? Session storage is not useful here as it cant share data with other tabs, so I haven't used session storage here. If I use event listeners like beforeunload, it is getting triggered even on page refresh, So what is the possible way to implement this concept in React?

Upon trying with taking count of tabs on loading and unloading, still, it is causing problems when there is one tab remaining. Can anyone please help me with an idea for this concept?

Answer (score 1):

Use sessionStorage. There's a trick that involves writing token to localStorage that would tell the sessionStorage that there's shared data between tabs which can be retrieved using that token. See https://medium.com/@marciomariani/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-5b6f42c6348c

I will try to paste some snippets from there, but really I don't know if that's allowed

Comment: is it based on using a window storage listener?, but as I went through this, I am a bit confused with the code, as you mentioned, could you please add some snippets so that it could be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `Broadcast Channel API`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API

This API allow you to communicate between tabs, iframes, etc. sitting on the same origin.

Comment: Reclade, I thought of this Broadcast channel, but I am just thinking about how to implement this closing tab in this way? Any idea or suggestion on how to use this dude?

Comment: What is that you try to achieve ?? If you want to remove localStorage on close, that's sessionStorage. So use sessionStorage and Broadcast Channel to share information (instead of using the localStorage for that)